# Swift 4 Decodable and List persistence in Realm

Tags: realm, swift4, realm-list, decodable

After migrating the project to swift 4 I started migrating my object's serialisation from JSON to Realm Object using Decodable. My objects has a list inside that is initialised as well in my `init(from decoder: Decoder)` method. In code:

```
class MyObj: RealmSwift.Object, Decodable {
    dynamic var id: String
    let fooList = List<Foo>()

    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        id = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .id)
        try? container.decode([Foo].self, forKey: .id)
                .forEach(fooList.append) 
    }

    override class func primaryKey() -> String? { return "id" }
}
```

Inspecting the object after the serialisation, everything is fine. all the data are correctly serialised. Then later on in the networking layer the newly serialised object is persisted in realm:

```
realm.beginWrite()
realm.add(myObjInstance, update: true)
try! realm.commitWrite()
```

When I re-fetch the object from realm:

```
realm.object(ofType: MyObj.self, forPrimaryKey: id)
```

The result is a MyObj instance, but with fooList empty.

Clearly I'm doing something wrong, but what? :D

Comment: Please include the actual JSON response you are trying to decode in your question. Also, did you check, does the line decoding `[Foo]` actually execute successfully, is the `forEach` actually called?

Comment: Hi @DávidPásztor as I said the Decoding part is not an issue here. All the decoding is perfect. If I inspect the instance all is there. It's when I re-fetch the object with that id from realm that the list is empty. Foo is a Decoding Realm Object as well so I expect it to be persisted, but it is not.

Comment: So what your saying is, after decoding the `fooList` List is not empty, but after you persist it in Realm and later query it, the `fooList` property becomes empty? Did you try inspecting the Realm file using Realm browser to see if the `Foo` objects are actually saved or not? Other than the use of the `forEach` to append the `Foo` objects to the `List`, I have pretty much the same code working just fine. In my version, instead of `.forEach(fooList.append)`, I use `let fooArray = try container.decode([Foo].self,forKey: .id); fooList.append(objectsIn: fooArray)`, so I'd give that a try here also

Comment: I'm saying that `realm.object(ofType: MyObj.self, forPrimaryKey: id)` returns an object with fooList empty. I'm talking about a new instance returned from the Realm fetch method. The instance decoded by the networking layer works just fine. it's when I get the object with the same id from realm that I don't get what I expect.